# text search in mongodb - php

Tags: php, mongodb, full-text-search

I am trying to implement text search in MongoDB using PHP. I have created necessary text index on the collection and Mongo queries with operators $text , $search are working fine. However, using PHP, I am facing a few errors to search documents in mongodb collection.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<body>

<h3>MongoDB Test</h3>
<h2>Text search - Amazon reviews</h2>
<br>
<form method="post">
search: <input type="text" name="term"><br><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>

<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

   $term = $_REQUEST['term'];
   // connect to mongodb : default is localhost:27017
   $m = new MongoClient();

   echo "Connection to database successfully"."</br>";
   // select a database
   $db = $m->selectDB('test');
   $collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'reviews');

$query = array('$text' => array('$search'=> $term));
$cursor = $collection->find($query);
var_dump($cursor);
echo '<table border="1"><tr><td>Review Title</td><td>Author</td><td>Rating</td></tr>';

foreach ($cursor as $doc) {

  echo '<tr>';
         echo '<td>'.$doc['Reviews.Title'].'</td>'.
           '<td>'.$doc['Reviews.Author'].'</td>'.
           '<td>'.$doc['Reviews.Overall'].'</td>';
  echo '</tr>';


}

echo '</table>';
}
?>
```

> Error: 
>   Connection to database successfully
>   object(MongoCursor)#4 (0) { } 
>   Notice: Undefined index: Reviews.Title in C:\xampp\htdocs\MongoSearch\index.php on line 41

Notice: Undefined index: Reviews.Author in C:\xampp\htdocs\MongoSearch\index.php on line 42

Notice: Undefined index: Reviews.Overall in C:\xampp\htdocs\MongoSearch\index.php on line 43

Notice: Undefined index: Reviews.Title in C:\xampp\htdocs\MongoSearch\index.php on line 41

Notice: Undefined index: Reviews.Author in C:\xampp\htdocs\MongoSearch\index.php on line 42

Notice: Undefined index: Reviews.Overall in C:\xampp\htdocs\MongoSearch\index.php on line 43

---

Can anyone point out the mistake in this code? Text index is properly built on this collection. Below mongo query is working fine on the collection.

```
db.getCollection('reviews').find({$text: {$search : 'terrible'}})
```

This is structure of the resulting document:

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("571a3c99fef93833794475d4"),
    "Reviews" : {
        "Title" : "Terrible, Terrible, Terrible!",
        "Author" : "authoradasdjlasd",
        "Overall" : "1.0",
        "Content" : "battery will die.I hope this helps!!",
        "Date" : "September 9, 2013"
    },
    "ProductInfo" : {
        "Name" : "Kyocera Rise (Virgin Mobile)",
        "ProductID" : "B008P2UVT0"
    }
}
```

The main problem here is that I am getting 0 documents as a result. I doubt on mongo query translation to PHP code. 
i.e.

```
   $query = array('$text' => array('$search'=> $term));
   $cursor = $collection->find($query);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It literally means that your `$doc` does not have `Reviews.Title` key. I don't know what's your structure but it looks like you are unnecessary adding `Reviews.` to the key or if it's embedded document you should be accessing it with `$doc['Reviews']['Title']`. Either way, try `var_dump`ing your `$doc` to see what is in it.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question. I have also added structure of my document. You are correct that $doc does not have any reviews at all, but my main question is about that only. Why I am getting 0 documents using PHP when I already get documents with just normal mongo query using mongo shell.  Is there anything wrong in query translation to PHP?